# excel formulas not working in structured table protected cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Structured `Table1`=

```
     A     B        C
    QTY  Price    QTY*Price
1    3     3      =A*B
2
3
```

Column `QTY` & `Price` are not locked
while Column `QTY*Price` is locked & hidden as it has a formula.

Problem:
When I enter `QTY` and `Price` the formula in column QTY*Price is not calculating. Seems to be frozen as sheet is protected.
I want to keep sheet protected btw.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think being locked affects this.  Are calculations enabled and set to Automatic?  Does it update if you hit F9 (calculate) or CTRL+ALT+F9 (rebuild sheets and calculate)?

Comment: @Byron yes automatic calculation is working. Issue happens when all table rows are deleted then protect cell formula will not work automatically. Check this http://i.stack.imgur.com/M4mWi.gif